# How to define metafunctions by undefined types?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-value, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

Please consider metafunctions like

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, T N, T M>
struct Sum : std::integral_constant <T, N + M> {};

template <typename T, T N, T M>
struct Product : std::integral_constant <T, N * M> {};
```

Their result can be extracted through the `::value` member:

```
static_assert (Sum <int, 3, 4>::value == 7, "3 + 4 == 7");
static_assert (Product <int, 2, 5>::value == 10, "2 * 5 == 10");
```

Both metafunctions have a similar static signature. That is, they associate a `T` to every pair of `T`'s where `T` is subject to the same restrictions as those imposed by `std::integral_constant` and either being summable or multipliable. So we can create a generic metafunction to do the evaluation.

```
template <typename T, template <typename U, U, U> class F, T N, T M>
struct EvaluateBinaryOperator : std::integral_constant <T, F <T, N, M>::value> {};

static_assert (EvaluateBinaryOperator <int, Sum, 3, 4>::value == 7, "3 + 4 == 7");
static_assert (EvaluateBinaryOperator <int, Product, 2, 5>::value == 10, "2 * 5 == 10");
```

When used solely in this form, it feels redundant to to pollute `Sum` and `Product` with the structure of an `std::integral_constant`. To show you that we can do without indeed, please consider the following:

```
template <typename T, T N, T M, T R = N + M>
struct Sum;

template <typename T, T N, T M, T R = N * M>
struct Product;

template <typename> struct EvaluateBinaryOperator;

template <typename T, template <typename U, U, U, U> class F, T N, T M, T R>
struct EvaluateBinaryOperator <F <T, N, M, R> > : std::integral_constant <T, R> {};

static_assert (EvaluateBinaryOperator <Sum <int, 3, 4> >::value == 7, "3 + 4 == 7");
static_assert (EvaluateBinaryOperator <Product <int, 2, 5> >::value == 10, "2 * 5 == 10");
```

Instead of using members of `Sum` and `Product`, we specialize on a default argument and extract it only in `EvaluateBinaryOperator`. As an added bonus, `Sum` and `Product` can remain without definition, rendering them trivially non-inferrable and non-constructable and the syntax looks much cleaner too. Now, here's the catch. What if we would like all our metafunctions to have a uniform static interface? That is, what if we introduce

```
template <typename...> struct Tuple;

template <typename T, T> struct Value;
```

and require all our metafunctions to look like `template <typename> struct`? For instance,

```
template <typename> struct Sum;

template <typename T, T N, T M>
struct Sum <Tuple <Value <T, N>, Value <T, M> > > : 
    std::integral_constant <T, N + M> {};

template <typename> struct Product;

template <typename T, T N, T M>
struct Product <Tuple <Value <T, N>, Value <T, M> > > : 
    std::integral_constant <T, N * M> {};
```

Now, we would like to transform them to something like:

```
template <typename, typename> struct Sum;

template <typename T, T N, T M, typename R = Tuple <Value <T, N + M> > >
struct Sum <Tuple <Value <T, N>, Value <T, M> >, R>;

template <typename, typename> struct Product;

template <typename T, T N, T M, typename R = Tuple <Value <T, N * M> > >
struct Product <Tuple <Value <T, N>, Value <T, M> >, R>;
```

Such that we can extract values with

```
template <typename> struct Evaluate;

template <template <typename, typename> class F, typename I, typename O>
struct Evaluate <F <I, O> > {
    typedef O Type;
};

static_assert (std::is_same <
    Evaluate <Sum <Tuple <Value <int, 3>, Value <int, 4> > > >::Type,
    Tuple <Value <int, 7> >
>::value, "3 + 4 == 7");
static_assert (std::is_same <
    Evaluate <Product <Tuple <Value <int, 2>, Value <int, 5> > > >::Type,
    Tuple <Value <int, 10> >
>::value, "2 * 5 == 10");
```

Those of you familiar with the C++ standard will immediately point to 14.5.5/8: "The template parameter list of a specialization shall not contain default template argument values.", accompanied by the teasing footnote: "There is no way in which they could be used.". Indeed, feeding just about any modern compiler this code yields a compiler error on the `Sum` and `Product` template specializations about violation of the standard. Apart from proving the aforementioned footnote to lack the imagination of the author; we've created ourselves a valid use case for them.

My question can now be put: Are there any other ways to achieve a similar effect where `Sum` and `Product` remain undefined / incomplete types, thereby trivially being non-inferrable and non-constructable, while still carrying responsibility for performing the operation? Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess my main question is... why? Metaprogramming is already very complex, which is why we rely on conventions to give us a hook to understand code... conventions like having metafunctions "return" a typedef named `type`. Your initial solution is great, why would you even want the rest?

Comment: I'm agree with @Barry: Why you would need to constraint your metafunctions to have one boxed parameter only? Instead, provide a variadic interface and partially specialize on the number of args. Also this has the bonus that a template `template<template<typename...> class F> struct lazy` can wrap (store) any of your metafunctions. e.g. `lazy<Add>` becomes a type (A first class citizen in tmp)

Comment: @Barry Forbidding to infer from or construct a type catches programming errors early on. If we have lots of metafunctions returning by `::type`, selecting a wrong one is an easy source of mistakes. By selecting only a few of them to be inferred from, we restrict on ambiguity.

Comment: @Manu343726 I agree, we could also adopt the convention that all metafunctions are of type `template <typename...> class`. Perhaps you would be interested to work out what the construction would look like in that case?

Comment: @dyp Could you explain why that would not be possible? Doesn't the (non-compiling) code above give you a hint of how a compiler might do this or do you forsee any other problems with default parameters for specializations? Please elaborate if possible, because I sincerely think the code above can be given unique semantics in C++.

Comment: *"footnote to lack the imagination of the author"* I still don't see how they could be used: Your primary template specifies the need for two user-supplied arguments, yet you want the user to only supply one.

Comment: Sorry, my earlier (now removed) comment was written under the confusion of several versions of the code.

Comment: @dyp The second argument is to be deduced by the template and is a default argument. Similar to what I show with `template <typename T, T N, T M, T R = N + M> struct Sum;` for instance.

Comment: `template <typename, typename> struct Sum;` says the second argument is *mandatory*, not *optional*. `template <typename T, T N, T M, typename R = Tuple <Value <T, N + M> > >
struct Sum <..>` does not add a default argument to the primary template. Hence, a user still has to provide `Sum<Tuple<Value<1>, Value<2>>, Value<3>>` the second argument.

Comment: @dyp Yes, that is correct and it's precisely the reason for the desire of having default arguments on specializations. `template <typename, typename> struct Sum;` forces you to provide two types. The second of which, if we want it to be a default parameter, needs to be given a value in this signature already, which is too early for us. We could also look at this from a different perspective. What if, `Sum <>` is just an incomplete type that needs to be rebound to two types to get an actual type?

Comment: @dyp Or similarly, what if `Sum <Tuple <Value  <int, 3> > >` is and incomplete type that needs to be passed another type in the `Tuple` to form a complete type? Essentially, we would need currying for metafunctions to do so. However, note that by using `Tuple`s we get currying for free! This is part of the motivation for this question in the first place. Clearly, this kind of currying can't be combined with having incomplete types anywhere. That's why I am asking if there's an alternative way to achieve a similar result.

Comment: *"Yes, that is correct and it's precisely the reason for the desire of having default arguments on specializations."* A specialization is not a separate template. You define a common "interface" with the primary template. Default arguments don't help. What you want looks to me more like a combined restriction + pattern matching in the primary template. I suggest you consider (or ask for) alternatives; e.g. you could write `template<..> struct Sum<..> : result_is<Tuple<Value<N+M>> {};` and define `result_is` such that it cannot be instantiated (all ctors deleted); or use alias templates.

Comment: @dyp Great idea! Keep them up. I can see how `result_is` will take responsibility in enforcing the relevant concepts. Still too bad it is not able to utilize the same 'quirk'? or a similar pattern that enabled the fourth listing of my question to compile. Would you qualify this fourth listing as bad practice, though?

Answer (score 4):

Metaprogramming is complicated. It wasn't a designed feature of the language, it was discovered. As such, it's hard to do right - so people came up with conventions for how to call metafunctions so give other programmers guideposts to understand the code. One of the most important conventions is that to get the result of a metafunction, you do this:

```
typename metafunc<some_args...>::type
```

Your various proposals for writing `Sum` do not fit that convention at all, and I think even many very experienced template metaprogrammers would have a hard time following what you're doing - and would even rely on changes to the rules of how template partial specialization works. It is not a compelling example at all to change those rules though. Let me instead propose something better.

Types, in metaprogramming, are first-class citizens. Everything just works with types. Values and template templates are not. They are clunky at best. The fact that you need to write `Sum<int, 1, 2>` sucks. Furthermore it's basically impossible to write generic metafunctions when you have to allow for values or template templates of varying numbers of arguments. So let's try to keep everything a type.

One of the concepts that Boost.MPL uses is a [metafunction class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction-class.html). We can C++11-ify it a bit, and say that a metafunction class is some class that looks like:

```
struct C {
    template <typename... Args> // doesn't have to be variadic
    using apply = /* whatever */;
};
```

Using that idea, we can say that `EvaluateBinaryOperator` would look like:

```
template <typename Op, typename A1, typename A2>
struct EvaluateBinaryOperator {
    using type = typename Op::template apply<A1, A2>;
};
```

Note how clean it is when everything is a type! Sure, the syntax for calling `apply` is less than steller, but that's very simple. In fact, we can generalize to:

```
template <typename Op, typename... Args>
struct EvaluateOperator {
    using type = typename Op::template apply<Args...>;
};
```

Easy. Now let's go back to `Sum`. Types are first class citizens, so it will no longer take values. It will take types. But we can still enforce that the types are integral constants with the same type thusly:

```
class Sum {
    template <typename, typename >
    struct impl;

    template <typename T, T a, T b>
    struct impl<std::integral_constant<T, a>,
                std::integral_constant<T, b>>
    {
        using type = std::integral_constant<T, a+b>;
    };

public:
    template <typename T, typename U>
    using apply = typename impl<T, U>::type;
};
```

This fits the model of metafunction class, so we can use it with `EvaluateOperator`, for instance:

```
std::cout << EvaluateOperator<Sum, 
                    std::integral_constant<int, 1>,
                    std::integral_constant<int, 2>
                    >::type::value << std::endl; // prints 3
```

Instantiating `impl` with two types that aren't integral constants of the same underlying type will give you the incomplete type error that you wanted.

Using metafunction classes also gives you the advantage of being able to curry. You can't really "return" a class template from a metafunction, but you *can* return a metafunction class:

```
template <typename Op, typename... Args>
struct curry {
    struct type {
        template <typename... OtherArgs>
        using apply = typename EvaluateOperator<Op, Args..., OtherArgs...>::type;
    };
};

using Add1 = curry<Sum, std::integral_constant<int, 1>>::type;
std::cout << Add1::apply<
                 std::integral_constant<int, 5>
             >::type::value << std::endl; // prints 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. It clearly illustrates how we can bring the code to a more 'standard' form, ulitizing Boost.MPL and using complete types. Trust me, this is also my preferred choice of implementation. However, the ability to use default template arguments for computation, as illustrated in the fourth listing of my question, raised a question to me: can we apply it in a broader context? Just out of curiosity. Apparently, the answer is no and from what you say it's considered bad practice as well. Before closing the question though, I would like to see if more ideas pops up.

Comment: @RalphLangendam But you *can't* use default template arguments like that. Furthermore, even if you could, it doesn't seem very usable at all. I see no upside from such construction.

Comment: @RalphLangendam Also, it's a reasonable question. Don't close it.